# how to manage terraform multiple file and want to run in different (manual) order

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have 5 terraform configuration files and with remote exec on all files on the same folder.

```
node1.tf
node2.tf
node3.tf
node4.tf
node5.tf
```

so now I want the first-run node1.tf and as soon as it is provision completed then run the node2.tf file
and soo on...

how can I achieve this

if now I hit `terraform apply` then it will provision all the files in a different order or may be in random order but I want my files would be run one by one.

Comment: That is not how terraform works and is supposed to work, terraform basically combines all the files in one, builds their dependency tree and then deploys the stuff according to that. If you want a order you need to add `depends_on` relations between different resources or modules.

Comment: @luk2302 could you guide me how i run with depends_on when node1.tf is provision then after node2.tf will be start

Comment: You can't do this. Each file must be in a separate folder.

Comment: @Marcin i will do this on separate folder could you let me know how I did this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted already in the comments, there seem to be a misunderstanding on your side on how Terraform works. Terraform is not a programming language. Even more so not a procedural programming language - i.e. it's **not** the case that what you have in the `.tf` files is executed top down (or in any specific order).

Instead Terraform code is declarative. I.e. you specify the desired state and the Terraform tool's job is to identify how to get from the current state to the desired one.

Most likely either Terraform is not the right tool for your task. Or you should re-consider your constraints.

What @Marcin suggests in the comments is also you can hack things with a file structure like this:

```
dir1/
node1.tf
dir2/
node2.tf
dir3/
node3.tf
...
```

And then run:

```
cd dir1 && terraform apply && cd ..
cd dir2 && terraform apply && cd ..
cd dir3 && terraform apply && cd ..
```

which in theory is what you are asking for. But be warned that opens up for a lot of trouble with how you are going to maintain inconsistent state (e.g. a problem happening during dir2's apply, etc.)